# How to complete time series data with some missing dates with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have dataset with missing dates like this.

```
date,value
2015-01-01,7392
2015-01-03,4928
2015-01-06,8672
```

This is what I expect to achieve.

```
date,value
2015-01-01,7392
2015-01-02,7392 # ffill 1st
2015-01-03,4928
2015-01-04,4928 # ffill 3rd
2015-01-05,4928 # ffill 3rd
2015-01-06,8672
```

---

I tried a lot, I read the documentation, but I could not find a solutioni. I guessed using df.resample('d',fill_method='ffill'), but I am not still reaching here. Could anyone help me to solve the problem?

This is what I did.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(text,sep="\t",index_col='date')
>>> df.index = df.index.to_datetime()
>>> index = pd.date_range(df.index[1],df.index.max())
```

Here I get the DatetimeIndex from 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-06.

```
>>> values = [ x for x in range(len(index)) ]
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(values,index=index)
```

Next I am going to merge the original data and DatetimeIndex.

```
>>> df + df2

             0   value
2015-01-01 NaN NaN
2015-01-02 NaN NaN
2015-01-03 NaN NaN
2015-01-04 NaN NaN
2015-01-05 NaN NaN
2015-01-06 NaN NaN
```

NaN? I am puzzled.

```
>>> df3 = df + df2
>>> df3.info()

DatetimeIndex: 10 entries, 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-10
Data columns (total 2 columns):
value    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
```

The original value was int, but it converted into float.

What is my mistake?

Comment: What goes wrong when you try df.resample('d',fill_method='ffill')?

Comment: I wanted to add this as an edit in my answer, but you beat me to it. If there is nothing wrong with your suggestion then I will delete my answer.

Comment: I guess OP has tried that but something went wrong. I'm guessing the problem is about the time format (2015-01-02 is evaluated as Feb 1st rather than January 2nd). Feel free to add this to your answer by the way, it's OP's own solution not mine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=index)
df.combine_first(df2).fillna(method='ffill')
```

`combine_first` will replace `nan` values in `df2` with values from the original `df` when they exist. You can then fill the remaining `nan` values with `fillna`.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Your comment worked, and I achieved it!